# Pandas построение графика для определения накладывающихся друг на друга задач

Tags: python, pandas

У меня есть датафрейм с 3 колонками Type, Start, END. Type колонка указывает название повторяющейся задачи, Start и END время начала и окончания этой задачи. Например дф, с небольшой выборкой

```
    d1 = pd.DataFrame({
   'Type':['Update', 'Update', 'Update', 'Normal', 'Normal', 'Normal'],
   'Start':['2020-10-22 22:00:01', '2020-10-24 22:00:01', '2020-10-27 22:00:01', '2020-10-22 01:15:02', '2020-10-24 01:15:01', '2020-10-27 01:15:01'],
   'END':['2020-10-22 23:32:33', '2020-10-24 23:00:16', '2020-10-27 23:00:17', '2020-10-22 04:51:45', '2020-10-24 08:52:19', '2020-10-27 04:07:48']
})
```

и вот необходимо его развернуть примерно в следующий график
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

чтобы визуально было видно, как накладываются по времени разные активности

Comment: Мне кажется куда-то в сторону `Gantt Chart` надо смотреть https://plotly.com/python/gantt/ https://towardsdatascience.com/gantt-charts-with-pythons-matplotlib-395b7af72d72

Answer (score 3):

Если не заморачиваться серьезно с диаграммами Гантта, то можно сделать как-то так:

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.dates as dt

df = pd.DataFrame({
   'Type':['Update', 'Update', 'Update', 'Normal', 'Normal', 'Normal'],
   'Start':['2020-10-22 22:00:01', '2020-10-24 22:00:01', '2020-10-27 22:00:01', '2020-10-22 01:15:02', '2020-10-24 01:15:01', '2020-10-27 01:15:01'],
   'END':['2020-10-22 23:32:33', '2020-10-24 23:00:16', '2020-10-27 23:00:17', '2020-10-22 04:51:45', '2020-10-24 08:52:19', '2020-10-27 04:07:48']
})
df["Start"] = pd.to_datetime(df["Start"])
df["END"] = pd.to_datetime(df["END"])

bottoms = df.groupby("Type").ngroup()
ticks = list(df.groupby("Type").groups)

fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(12, 3))
plt.grid(axis="x")
ax.set_ylim(-.5,2)

colors = ["green" if x else "blue" for x in bottoms ]

ax.set_yticks([0,1])
ax.set_yticklabels(ticks)
ax = ax.xaxis_date()
ax = plt.bar(dt.date2num(df["Start"]), height=.5, width=dt.date2num(df["END"]) - dt.date2num(df["Start"]), bottom=bottoms, color=colors)

plt.show()
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]